# reportviewer not shown on form designer (c# winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I user reportviewer for my winform app!!!

now when i select reportviewer control from toolbox and add that to page controler, any thing not shown on form designer , but bottom of page the name of reportviewer will be seen!!!

i really confused for this problem !!!

this problem appeared when i make backup from my project !!! and before that i did't have any problem with report viewer!
(i set location and size of reportviewer manually but  ...)

```
 this.reportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
 this.reportViewer1.Name = "ReportViewer";
 this.reportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(396, 246);
 this.reportViewer1.TabIndex = 0;
 this.reportViewer1.Visible = true;
```

[image]

Comment: [MSDN Walkthrough Creating ReportViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252073.aspx)

Comment: Resize your form larger

Comment: i set location and size manually in form designer !!! i make screen shot little for smaller image file size !

Comment: in the past i faced to this problem and solved it but now i don't remember my solution!!!

Comment: Go into your form's designer class and make sure the form has the proper size, position, and visibility.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888198/4092887

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a workaround

this line Manual added
**this.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);**

on method 
**InitializeComponent**

Why when
Drag-drop control on the Windows Forms

Not added automatic

P.s
Sorry for my english

Comment: Microsoft's suggested workaround is to drop a panel on the form.  Add the reportviewer to the panel rather than the form. Ex: this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);

Then set the reportViewer's Dock property to Fill.
You can now resize the reportViewer but you still cannot interact directly with it.

This link to Microsoft's feedback page may draw attention to fix it:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/38324749-restore-the-visual-studio-designer-functionality-o

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it by updating the dll `Windows.ReportViewer.Winform` (version 10.0) to (version 11.0) with Nuget.

Comment: i create new project and replace that two file i said to my original project and my problem solved!

Comment: Great! I hope never have this problem again (was a f... s...) jejeje

Answer (score 2):

install version 11.0.3452.
It's  working for me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Prx.png).

Comment: it's too late for resolving issue :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Install the nuget package:-
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms

It will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

For those that didn't have the ReportViewer control in the Toolbox so they followed the instructions and added the control manually -- if you don't see the ReportViewer control after dragging the (now available) ReportViewer control, then right click on References in your project structure, then browse to the exact same location from where you took the `....WinForm.dll` or `WebForm.dll` and this time choose `...Designer.dll`.

Rebuild your project and try dragging again. This time the control should be visible on the form.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the same issue. Deleted the reference **Windows.ReportViewer.Winform and Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common** and dragged report viewer control on the form and added this line **this.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);** in  **private void InitializeComponent()**

Answer (score 0):

this is my problem several days ago. I try all the solutions based on my searches. But I found it myself. I uninstall all my report viewer nuget packages and search for nuget packages outside the visual studio. then found an installer saying that you have an older version of microsoft report viewer would you like to replace it? then click Yes install and after I try it... it works! amazing!