# Winforms ReportViewer not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, report-viewer2012

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012, I am trying to invoke my deployed reports using winforms, this is what i did.

1. I created a new c# winforms application
2. I went to the toolbox to look for the `ReportViewer` control(but it wasnt there)
   2.1 So i added it manually by right `clicking Toolbox > Choose Items > then i selected the report viewer`
3. After that i dragged and dropped it on the form(but it goes straight to the bottom tray and doesn't give me any options)

[image]

I have seen many questions that address the same issue but with no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` version 10, I am not sure why, but it was doing the same thing on my colleague's computer.

Here is what I did:

1. I download and installed `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` version 11.0.0.0
2. I went to the toolbox and `right clicked > Choose Items`
3. From there I deselected `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` version 10 and selected version 11.
4. I then went back to my solution to drag and drop the report viewer to my form, it worked

Answer (score 3):

I tried the accepted answer but it didn't work to me.

So, another solution could be:

In your `Designer.cs` file, you have to add this line *(manually)*:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1);
```

This is my example in a form called "FrmPreviewRpt1":

```
//
// FrmPreviewRpt1
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(725, 305);
this.Controls.Add(this.reportViewer1); // This is the new line.
this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2);
this.Name = "FrmPreviewRpt1";
this.Text = "FrmPreviewRpt1";
this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image: sample result]

The bad news with this approach is that you have to change the size *(and possibly other visible attributes)* in the Designer.cs file manually.